# longest path in undirected vs directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

I need to solve a longest path problem for graphs that are both directed and non-directed (unweighted in both cases).
For directed graph, it is pretty easy to find dynamic programming algorithms that are able to solve the problem in pseudopolynomial time, starting at some node, and calculating the longest path for subproblems until every problem has been looked at.

Can I do a similar thing for at non-directed graph? I cant seem to find any litterature about it?

Comment: Replace each edge by two directed edges. Now you have a directed graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every directed graph algorithm works on undirected graphs.  Simply treat each edge as two directed edges with the same weight.

Comment: how about algorithms that use a topological ordering? I cannot understand how I could perform one on a undirected graph

Comment: topological sorting works only in a DAG, a directed graph converted to undirected has obvious cycles (from every node to itself f.e)